# What will be the new features of Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric Ocelot?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04

What new features and changes will be done for Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is too early to talk about the features of Ubuntu 11.10 since the Ubuntu Developer Summit (UDS) for 11.10 has not taken place yet. You can find more info about UDS [here](http://summit.ubuntu.com/).

However one of the features that Mark Shuttleworth announced was the availability of Unity to all users regardless of their hardware. This essential means that Unity 2D would be the backup incase Unity 3D is not supported by your hardware.

Comment: And so thus, there is no longer any fallback to the classic desktop? Ouch.